# RFT :Pass arguments to the driver script through command line

Tags: rft

Is there a way to pass custom arguments to the RFT automation script through command line ?
I was trying to launch my driver script for automation(scripted in RFT 8.0.6) through command line and I was able to do so successfully. I wanted to pass the row number(iterator)- from where my test datapool should be read, as an argument to my driver script through command line. Is it a possibility to do so from commandline?
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
java.exe -jar rational_ft.jar -datastore <project_path> -playback <scriptName> -args one two three
```

The script will get 
 three arguments i.e  one two and three

Comment: Thanks Prakash but can you please tell how will this argument be parsed in my script ? Whats the code for reading this argument in my script ?

Comment: Never mind, I got it by trying args[0].toString(). Thanks for the help!